# Helm subcharts - one parent chart value mapping/cascading to multiple subchart values

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a Helm chart that has two subchart `dependencies`.

```yaml
dependencies:
- name: blah
  repository: blah/blah
  version: 2.3.4
  alias: blah
- name: yap
  repository: yap/yap
  version: 1.0.0
  alias: yap
```

The two subcharts have a value defined in their respective `values.yaml`. In one, it is called `foo`, and in the other, it is called `bar`, but from the perspective of the top-level chart, *they should both always have the same value*.

I would like to define one value in the top-level chart `values.yaml` that can be used to populate both of these subchart values.

I realise I can use the `global` values section for providing a single value to all subcharts, but from what I can see, this relies on the subcharts being written to *explicitly use* the value from `global`, which is no use if I am not the author of the subchart.

I also realise I can override the two subchart values in my top-level chart `values.yaml`:

```yaml
blah:
  foo: defaultValue
yap:
  bar: defaultValue
```

but then if the user wanted to override these values on the command line, they would have to supply the same value twice with different names:

```bash
helm install ... --set blah.foo="this is my required value" --set yap.bar="this is my required value"
```

... which isn't great.

Is there any way to map one top-level value to multiple subchart values?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Helm can't do this on its own.  You can't compute Helm values; there are some workarounds using `tpl` but again they require the chart to specifically support them.